# Sorting by integer value

Tags: bash, sorting, integer

I am writing a bash script and I am using

> `ps -e -o %cpu`

command.

I would like to have output of sorted `%cpu` values (descending). How to do that?
I know that I should use sort command but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you looking for something simple as `ps -e -o %cpu | sort -r` ?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 ps -e -o %cpu | sort -nr
```

`n` for numeric, `r` for reverse. If you also want to remove the header:

```
 ps -e -o %cpu | sed '1d' | sort -nr
```

Comment: One more question. I want to use read command but without having to click return button (enter) at the end.
Lets say... a script is running and if user presses 'q' button on the keyboard, the script ends

Answer (score 1):

ps has an inbuilt option that sorts its output, based on any field of choice. You can use

```
ps k -%cpu -e -o %cpu
```

Here, `k` sorts the output based on field provided and `-%cpu` is to sort it in descending order.

If you omit the `-` in front of the sort field then it will be sorted in ascending order.
Also note that you can give it multiple sort fields:

```
ps k -%cpu,-%mem -e -o %cpu,%mem
```

This sorts the output(in descending order for both) first based on the `%cpu` field and second based on `%mem` field.